# Get date member was created magento

Tags: magento-1.6

In magento, when a person becomes a member, the date "created_at" is saved with the profile.

How can I retrieve this information from magento. I can get the address info etc. but can't work out how to display / get the date a user created its account.

I tried the following:

```
echo Mage::getResourceModel('customer/customer_collection')->addAttributeToSelect('cr‌​eated_at');
```

But doesn't work.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Did you try this:

```
$customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->load(IDHERE);
//or
$customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->loadByEmail('test@test.com');

echo $customer->getCreatedAtTimestamp();
```

where exactly are you trying to get this? from within the customers session? or are you trying to get an arbitrary customer, rather than the current customer?

Comment: Unfortunately that's for products, I'm after the date a member registered. I need to call this from within the customer area, when they are logged in

Comment: minus is harsh here as all of those models do actually have a CreatedAt time stamp, it's when the row was inserted. Which in most cases will be when the user signed up..